# Search on new mobile toolbar is severely broken

Tags: bug, design, search-box, mobile

Looks like a new toolbar was released this week for mobile? I can't use the search bar anymore (and why is there 2 search options now?). Its width is next to nothing, same with the drop down menu. I can't see what I'm typing. And it messes up what I do manage to type in (ie, square brackets get reversed, etc).

[image]